# Using truffle-contract.js to load contract

Tags: truffle, javascript, truffle-contract

I am having an extremely easy contract called `Friend.sol`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Friend {

    string name;
    uint age;

    function setFriend(string _name, uint _age) public {
        name = _name;
        age = _age;
    }

    function getFriend() public constant returns (string, uint) {
        return(name, age);
    }
}
```

I deployed my contract on `ganache-cli`:

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0xa4d581c585527651c4a74a0d85ef2e21ac91a43e17f290f5f548d6e5f0686e22
  Migrations: 0xf741d74fb4d4eab8c044dc4b1c0dfb7a244a6922
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xca51a8f5124ef4f1dc8dfba5b9a9c1388cda003686309ff152b776600a64cf81
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying Friend...
  ... 0x9195ced6c131afaf1e735fc90464f9b94dd4215e909f463f06e51565b5e7e804
  Friend: 0x8a260eec4c77f82bd885b730f782f9bbe680dd64
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x008b78bf25c5aa93fb6b8f16367d006e68751a54550da32bcce382067ad1250d
Saving artifacts...
```

Within my frontend I am trying to access the contract via [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) and [truffle-contract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract):

```
<html>

<head>Truffle-Contract Test</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>

    <h1>I am Friend with...</h1>

    <h2 id="friend"></h2>

    <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">

    <label for="age" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" id="age">

    <button id="button">Update Friend</button>

</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/web3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Is there an injected web3 instance?
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        var web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
    } else {
        // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
        var web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);

    // Get Contract
    $.getJSON('./Friend.json', function (data) {
        // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with truffle-contract
        var FriendArtifact = data;
        var FriendContract = TruffleContract(FriendArtifact);

        // Set the provider for our contract
        FriendContract.setProvider(web3Provider);

        console.log("FriendContract:")
        console.log(FriendContract)

        // interact with the smart contract
        FriendContract.getFriend(function (error, result) {
            if (!error) {
                $("#friend").html(result[0] + ' (' + result[1] + 'years old)')
            } else {
                console.log(error)
            }
        })

        $("button").click(function () {
            FriendContract.setFriend($("name").val(), $("age").val())
        })
    });
</script>

</html>
```

However, when running my `lite-server` I get:

[image]

The error is, when I want to interact with my contract on the following line:

```
    FriendContract.getFriend(function (error, result) {
```

I also created a small [github repo](https://github.com/marcpre/learning-npm-truffle-contract) to show my entire code.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var friendinstance;
FriendContract.deployed().then(function(instance){
                 friendinstance = instance;                  
                 return friendinstance.getFriend();                  
               }).then(function(result) {
             console.log(result);
             var str=result.toString();
             var friendDetails=str.split(",");
             $('#friend').html("Name:"+friendDetails[0]+"<br>"+"Age:"+friendDetails[1]);           
           }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);          
      });
```

Comment: great you tried to answer. you can format a block of code by selecting the code sblock and pressing `Ctrl + K`. This post will be useful https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/372941

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forget `deployed` function.

```
FriendContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  car friend = instance;
  return frined.getFriend();
}).then(function(friends) {
```

link: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract#usage